# Delphi XE2 DataSnap Server - HTTPS 'Could not load certificate'

Tags: delphi, https, certificate, datasnap

I have an existing DataSnap server (Windows service) which is running fine on HTTP, and I now want to add HTTPS as an additional protocol.  I've obtained and installed an SSL certificate and generated a certificate file (.crt) and private key file (.key).  As a test, when using the Delphi XE2 DataSnap Server wizard and ticking 'HTTPS' to get the certificate page, I can reference the 2 files and click the 'Test' button which succeeds.  I've added an additional TDSHTTPService component and linked it to a TDSCertFiles component.  In my service startup event I'm setting the path to the 2 certificate files before starting the DSServer, in the DSCertFiles.CertFile and DSCertFiles.KeyFile  properties.  When trying to start the service I get the error :

> Could not load certificate. error:140AD002:SSL
>   routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file:system lib

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Does your code verify that the service actually can "see" the certificate files (it might be a path or permission problem)?

Comment: Hi, see my comment to Remy's answer - the component seems to look for the certificates in the path set at design-time only (maybe a bug?).

Comment: You can verify if it is a bug - if the error disappears as soon as you place the files in the design-time defined location. Otherwise, something is wrong with the service environment

Comment: Yes the error disappears when ensuring the files are in the design-time location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error code `0x140AD002` means `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file()` was not able to open the file.

Comment: Many thanks, it seems the DataSnap certificate component always looks for the certificate files in the path specified on the TDSCertFiles component at design-time, and ignores new paths that might be set in code at run-time.

Answer (score 5):

There is a well known bug in XE2 and XE3.

I've found this workaround.

**After** set the TDSCert properties and **before** start the DSHTTPServer, call this method:

```
DSCertFiles2.SetServerProperties(DSHTTPService2.HttpServer); //WORK AROUND
```