# DataSnap standalone server (EXE) using SSL- TLS 1.2 not supported?

Tags: delphi, https, tls1.2, delphi-10-seattle, datasnap

I've created a basic standalone DataSnap server, by using the project wizard and choosing the HTTPS protocol, along with a suitable SSL certificate.

Everything works fine, except for the fact that it only supports TLS 1.0. It's essential for my project that the server supports TLS 1.2. Is there anything I need to do to get it to use TLS 1.2? I've made sure I'm using the latest version of the OpenSSL DLLs.

I'm using Delphi 10.0 Seattle Update 1. I've looked at the bug fix list for Delphi 10.1 Berlin, and it mentions this one:

> [RSP-12760](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-12760) IPPeerAPI lacks TLS 1.2 Support

Looking at RSP-12760, it appears like this might be related, but I kinda think this is a fix for the HTTPS client rather than server.

Can anybody confirm if DataSnap servers built with 10.1 Berlin support TLS 1.2? Or should it work in 10.0 Seattle?

Comment: How did you get the proper certificate to use in a standalone DataSnap Server? I am new to SSL and HTTPS, and I need to use HTTPS in my datasnap standalone server.

Comment: Hi Henrique, see my answer to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348345/how-can-i-create-install-a-ssl-cert-for-a-standalone-datasnap-rest-server-on-loc

Comment: also see this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011628/delphi-xe2-datasnap-server-https-could-not-load-certificate

Answer (score 1):

I manage to do this with Delphi Rio 10.3.3.
Current datasnap does not make this changeable. Next version of Delphi XE seem  already allow this.
You can see it in the code

```
procedure TDSHTTPSServerIndy.InitializeServer;
var
 LIOHandler: IIPServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL;
begin
 inherited;
 if Server <> nil then
 begin
  LIOHandler := PeerFactory.CreatePeer(IPImplementationID, IIPServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL, Server.GetObject as TComponent) as IIPServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL;
```

> LIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method := TIPSSLVersionPeer.sslvTLSv1;

```
  LIOHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := TIPSSLModePeer.sslmServer;
  LIOHandler.SSLOptions.CertFile := FCertFile;
  LIOHandler.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := FRootCertFile;
  LIOHandler.SSLOptions.KeyFile := FKeyFile;

  LIOHandler.OnGetPassword := OnGetPassword;
  Server.IOHandler := LIOHandler;
  Assert(not Assigned(Server.OnConnect));
  Server.OnConnect := ServerOnConnect;
end;
```

end;

Because you can't recompile the datasnap source, make it so that the line can be changed in the derived class. Just :

1. Make our own class (ex: TNewClass) to replace TDSHTTPSServerIndy, then change the line of code to:

   LIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method := TIPSSLVersionPeer.sslvTLSv1_2;
2. Make new class, derived from TDSHttpService
3. Override `function TDSHTTPService.CreateHttpServer`, so it will used our new class at point 1 (TNewClass)

Note : TDSHTTPSServerIndy cannot be derived because the class is declared in the implementation section, so we have to recreate this class.

Make sure to used latest libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll, at least version 1.0.2.21.

If you need a complete code example, please email me.

Thanks.